# Sharepoint Hosted Add-In using External SQL Database

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, sql-server, sql

As in the title, I would like to create a Sharepoint hosted add-in that accesses data from an SQL database on my companies database. Is there any way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: In any way you need some service layer which will act as gateway between your add-in and database. In that case why do you need sharepoint-hosted add-in? Don't you think it's simpler to create provider hosted with Entity Framework or LINQ 2 SQL or any other data access?

Comment: @SergeiSergeev Yes I agree a provider hosted add-in makes more sense, however my supervisor said we can't host a server specifically for this so I have to use a sharepoint hosted one, if my understanding is correct. Thank you for the response.

Comment: You don't need an expensive server. A web app in Azure works as the "provider" of a provider hosted app. It costs a few dimes and requires little maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this can help you ..

```
function webProxy() {
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var request = new SP.WebRequestInfo();
request.set_url("http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Categories?$format=json");
request.set_method("GET");
var response = SP.WebProxy.invoke(context, request);

context.executeQueryAsync(success, fail);

function success() {
    if (response.get_statusCode() == 200) {
        var categories = JSON.parse(response.get_body());

        var message = jQuery("#message");
        message.text("Categories in the remote Northwind service:");
        message.append("<br/>");
        jQuery.each(categories.d.results, function (index, value) {
            message.append(value.CategoryName);
            message.append("<br/>");
        });

    } else {
        var errorMessage = response.get_body();
        alert(errorMessage);
    }
}

function fail(sender, args) {
    alert("Call failed. Error: " +
        args.get_message());
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the response. This shed some light on how I might approach it if my data could be got via a http request, but I don't know if this particular SQL server is capable of that. I will look into it.